# Quadratic Rings which are UFDs but not PIDs

Tags: abstract-algebra

D=-1,-2,-3,-7 and-11 are the only five negative square free integers for which the corresponding quadratic Rings are Euclidean domains. Also D=-19,-41,-43 and-167 are the only four square free negative integers for which the  corresponding quadratic rings are PIDs but not EDs. Are there any negative square free integers <-167 for which the corresponding quadratic rings are UFDs but not PIDs? Thank you in advance for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by "quadratic rings" you mean the integer ring of a quadratic extension of $\Bbb Q$.

The answer is then "no".

The integer ring of any number field is a [Dedekind domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain). It is a standard result that a ring is a PID if and only if it is a Dedekind domain and a UFD.

The proof can be found e.g. [here](https://planetmath.org/pidandufdareequivalentinadedekinddomain).

Comment: More generally PIDs are precisely the UFDs of dimension $\le 1,\,$ see the dupe.